# va_arg with wide char in c, how to handle %S

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement my own `printf`, I have an issue handling wide char `%S`.

```
void    my_printf(char *format, ...)
{
    char            *traverse;
    va_list         arg;

    va_start(arg, format);
    traverse = format;
    while (*traverse)
    {
        if (*traverse == '%')
        {
            *traverse++;
            if (*traverse == 'S')
                printf("%S\n", va_arg(arg, wchar_t));
            *traverse++;
        }
        else
            putchar(*traverse++);
    }
    va_end(arg);
}
```

> warning: format specifies type 'wchar_t *' (aka 'int *') but the argument has type 'wchar_t' (aka 'int') [-Wformat]
>                                   printf("%S\n", va_arg(arg, wchar_t));

when I use following code `printf` works fine.

```
printf("%S\n", L"Some String");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a pointer and retrieving an integer. The types of `L"Some String"` and `va_arg(arg, wchar_t)`, do not match.

Retrieve a pointer instead:

```
 va_arg(arg, wchar_t*)
```

---

The line `*traverse++;` is not correct, the dereference is redundant. It should be simply: `traverse++;`

---

On a side note, your code doesn't do any input checking and a malicious string will cause undefined behavior. This will happen if the character `'%'` is the last character, the iterator `traverse` will point to one beyond the last element in the array and the check `while (*traverse)` will dereference it.